# Cannot See Worker Processes Icon in IIS

Tags: iis-7.5, worker-process

When I look at the Features View for a site in IIS7.5 there is no icon for Worker Processes in the IIS group. Do I need to configure a setting or install a feature/role to make it appear?

Comment: Did you solve this? I also cannot see the "worker processes" icon. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Osprey. No, I am afraid I still have no idea why the icon does not display.

Answer (score 14):

Had the same issue, finally found the solution.

To see the Worker Processes icon you have to click on the top level server node not an individual site.

Then you'll see all the processes and you can click on any of them to see the currently running pages.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer, as people often click the "site" rather than a "server node" and expect to see the worker process icon.

Answer (score 0):

**To view a list of worker processes**

```
1.You can perform this procedure by using the user interface (UI), by running Appcmd.exe commands in a command-line window, by editing configuration files directly, or by writing WMI scripts.
```

**User Interface**

To Use the UI...

```
Open IIS Manager.In the Connections pane, select the server node in the tree.In Features View, double-click Worker Processes.View the list of worker processes in the grid.
```

**Command-line**

To view a list of worker processes, use the following syntax:

```
appcmd list wps
```

For more details..please check the below link

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771273(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks Tatarano. Do you know why the worker processes are not visible in my IIS UI (this was my question)?

Comment: I am not sure.Make sure website and app pools are running...then it must have to show worker processes state.

Comment: Provide me the exact error what you are getting while you are accessing the worker process tab....it's something like below?

http://blogs.iis.net/robert_mcmurray/archive/2008/10/01/category-does-not-exist-error-when-viewing-iis-worker-processes-in-iis-manager.aspx

Comment: Thanks Tatarao. The website and app pools are running. I cannot open the worker process tab because I cannot see the icon.

Answer (score 0):

"Open IIS Manager. In the Connections pane, select the server node in the tree."

This is the very top of the tree which may be a computer name / domain user name. Only while this node is selected will the Features View pane show the "Worker Processes" option.  It may help to select Group By : "No Grouping" so that the worker processes option appears at the end of the list.